# Pandas DataFrame row wise comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like following.

```
       id  label_x label_y
0        1    F    R
1        2    F    F
2        3    F    F
3        4    F    F
4        5    F    F
```

Now I want to count occurrences of label_x and label_y are equal and not equal. In this case there is only one occurrence of not equal and 4 occurrences of equal.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ["1","2","3","4","5"],
                'label_x'  : ["F","F","F","F","F"], 'label_y' : ["R","F","F","F","F"]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(df.label_x == df.label_y).value_counts()
```

Many ways to to that, including the above...

```
In [43]: (df.label_x == df.label_y).value_counts()
Out[43]:
True     4
False    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your simple solution.

Comment: This does not account for `np.nan == np.nan` equaling `False`

Comment: Neither does his sample data :-)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution. Is that the best one?

```
def compare(x):
    if x[1] == x[2]:
        return 'yes'
    else:
        return 'no'

df['result'] =  df.apply(compare, axis=1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'count' : df.groupby( ["result"] ).size()}).reset_index()
```